# New activity from a button in navigationbar

Tags: android-intent, android-activity

I'm having trouble in starting a new activity from a button in navigation bar.
The below line is creating an error.

```
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(NavigationDrawerFragment.this, AddIntake.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following::

```
@Override
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
    switch(position) {
          case 0:
              startActivity(new Intent(this, AddIntake.class));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks but I've solved this using.

Intent myIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), AddIntake.class);